# Pip error shows up when I enter any and every pip command

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

When I tried to install discord.py, I saw an **error**. When I simply enter the pip command, I see this **error** again . I tried other pip commands, result was same. I reinstalled python but it did not help.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.progress.bar import Bar, FillingCirclesBar, IncrementalBar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.progress
```

Comment: Can you try run
```python --version```
If the python you're using is a version 2.x.x, then it is not compatible with pipx. You need at least python version 3.6.

Comment: I use python 3.8.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have python 3.4 or later pip may not be installed.

To check if it is installed use:

```
C:\Users\Your Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>pip --version.
```

If it isn't installed - follow this link: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_pip.asp